# Azure Databricks PAT token creation for Azure Service Principal Name

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I could not add Azure AD Service Principal Name into Azure Databricks through portal but I was able to add my Service Principal with help of Databricks APIs Endpoints. How can I create PAT Token for my Service Principal Name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the service principal to create an Azure Active Directory Token and use that to authenticate into Databricks.

To create an AAD token

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client-id>&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d&client_secret=<application-secret>' \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

Replace `<client-id>` and `<application-secret>` with the application ID and secret of your service principal and `<tenant-id>` with your tenant ID.
The response will include the value of the access token

```json
{
    "access_token": "<token value>"
}
```

Since you have already added the service principal into the Databricks workspace, so now you can directly use the generated token to invoke the Databricks REST endpoints as the service principal:

```sh
curl -X GET \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <token-value>' \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/clusters/list
```

You can also create additional tokens for the service principal using the Databricks Token API

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer <token-value>' \
--data '{ "comment": "This is an example token", "lifetime_seconds": 7776000 }' \
https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/token/create
```

More details are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--get-an-azure-active-directory-access-token).

Comment: This works for me. Thanks!
The api/2.0/token-management/on-behalf-of/tokens doesn't work at all. Databricks need to do better on documentation...

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** You add the Azure AD service principal to a workspace using the [SCIM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/scim/).

> Unfortunately, you cannot create Azure Databricks token programmatically.

You’ll use an Azure Databricks personal access token (PAT) to authenticate against the Databricks REST API. To create a PAT that can be used to make API requests:

1. Go to your Azure Databricks workspace.
2. Click the user icon in the top-right corner of the screen and click User Settings.
3. Click Access Tokens > Generate New Token.
4. Copy and save the token value.

Even for creating using APIs, initial authentication to this API is the same as for all of the Azure Databricks API endpoints: you must first authenticate as described in [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication#authentication).

For more details, refer [Tutorial: Run a job with an Azure service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals)

Comment: Actually, My Azure AD service principals are available at Databricks. Now, I want to create PAT for service principal. How to login databricks console using service principal and create PAT. Is it possible for admin.

Answer (score 0):

After adding service principal to databricks, you can use curl to create a databrick token/PAT for the service principal.

```
curl -X POST \
${DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/token-management/on-behalf-of/tokens \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${DATABRICKS_TOKEN}" \
--data @create-service-principal-token.json \
| jq .
```

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/service-principals.html#step-2-create-the-databricks-access-token-for-the-databricks-service-principal