# GET request to databricks jobs API with Azure Token, Incorrect Claim Exception

Tags: azure-databricks, jobs, azure-service-principal, databricks-workflows

I am using the jobs API to get the status of the databricks job created by azure service principal. I create the azure token using the code below

```
import requests
import json
from databricks_cli.sdk.service import JobsService
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
import time 

#generating toekn request for service principal
sp_id = dbutils.secrets.get("scope name", "key")
sp_sec = dbutils.secrets.get("scope name", "key")
token_endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<databricks-instance>/oauth2/token"
token_request_data = {
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id": sp_id,
    "client_secret": sp_sec,
    "scope" :"2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default"
}

#send the request to get the token
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data= token_request_data)
token_sp= response.json()["access_token"]
```

Then I can use this token successfully to run the databricks job. However when I want to get the status of the job using the same token, I get this error:

```
#send the request using run ID to get the state of the job with service principal token 

uri = "https://adb-1366553829746932.12.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/runs/get?run_id=831336"
headers = {
             "Authorization":f"Bearer {token_sp}",
             "Content-Type":"application/json",
             }

response=requests.get(uri,headers = headers)
response.text

'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 400 io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d, but was: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /api/2.1/jobs/runs/get. Reason:\n<pre>    io.jsonwebtoken.IncorrectClaimException: Expected aud claim to be: 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d, but was: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.</pre></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

I can get the job status if I use the PAT instead of service principal token.

I am not sure why this token works for POST request but not the GET request.

Comment: A best practice is that a PAT is suitable for administrative configuration tasks, but Azure AD tokens are preferred for production workloads.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP sure! that's why we are using azure ad tokens for our production workloads and we are trying to figure out how to get the job status using it instead of PAT. I am not sure if I understand the point you're making here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the not completely correct URL for the AAD token generation service. Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token), it should be `/oauth2/v2.0/token`, not `/oauth2/token` (this is old version that doesn't use scope, but need to receive resource id).  You also need to change `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default` to `2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default`

Here is the working code:

```py
import requests
import json
import time 

#generating toekn request for service principal
sp_id = "..."
sp_sec = dbutils.secrets.get("scope", "secret")
tenant_id = "..."

token_endpoint = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
token_request_data = {
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id": sp_id,
    "client_secret": sp_sec,
    "scope" :"2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default"
}
response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data= token_request_data)
token_sp= response.json()["access_token"]
```

And then we can use it:

```py
headers = { 'Authorization': f'Bearer {token_sp}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
url = "https://adb-....azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.text
```

and it gives normal list of clusters:

```
Out[10]: {'clusters': [{'cluster_id': '...',
   'creator_user_name': '....',
   'driver': {'private_ip': '10.1.4.5',
    'node_id': '78368a91af7a4b4f8d4e97f65790b7c2',
    'instance_id': 'f7ce71746e1c4d1696817f5ead0765b5',
    'start_timestamp': 1682060511817,
    'node_attributes': {'is_spot': False},
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same thing in my environment and successfully ran the job as per the above requirement with status.

[image]

**Modified your code as per the above requirement, generated a bearer token, set up authentication and perform GET request to get job run status**

```
import requests
import json

# set up authentication
token = 'dapi54bxxxxxxxxxxxaf75c2536acd6eaa'
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}

run_id1 = '55xx'
endpoint = f'/api/2.0/jobs/runs/get?run_id={run_id1}'

#GET request to get job run status
resp = requests.get(f'https://adb-8411xxxxxxx.13.azuredatabricks.net{endpoint}', headers=headers)

# Check the response status code
if resp.status_code == 200:
    resp_json = json.loads(resp.text)
    job1_status = response_json['state']['life_cycle_state']
    job1_result = response_json['state']['result_state']
    
    # Print the job run status and result state
    print(f'Job run status: {job1_status}')
    print(f'Job run result: {job1_result}')
    
    if job1_result == 'SUCCESS':
        print('Job Completed Successfully.')
    elif job1_result == 'FAILED':
        print('Job Encountered an Error.')
else:
    print(f'Error: {resp.status_code} - {resp.text}')
```

**Successfully executed the code with Job run status:**

[image]

Comment: I think you are using PAT token and not Azure token, is that correct? If yes, then that doesn't solve this issue since I have already mentioned that the code works with PAT.

Comment: hi @Rio, yes you are correct I am using PAT, follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792583/azure-databricks-pat-token-creation-for-azure-service-principal-name) thread generate bearer token. Replace generated bearer token with the PAT token. It will fix your problem.

Comment: Yea I can't use PAT, the service principal is running this job and the status should be returned using service principal AD token not PAT.

Comment: @Rio A best practice is that a PAT is suitable for administrative configuration tasks, but Azure AD tokens are preferred for production workloads.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals

Comment: PAT isn't recommended on Azure for any task. I need to get doc team to fix that